# Mysql sort by time (hourly)

Tags: mysql

I am trying to figure out how to sort by time hourly with the following dataset.

```
hm,total_count,avg_count,max_count
-------------------------------------
'23:15','17','5.6667','9'
'23:45','19','3.1667','5'
'06:15','13','6.5000','9'
'05:15','22','4.4000','7'
'05:45','12','6.0000','11'
'04:15','22','4.4000','6'
'04:45','14','4.6667','7'
'03:45','24','2.4000','5'
'02:45','82','5.4667','13'
'01:45','98','6.1250','13'
'00:45','59','4.2143','11'
```

My query:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`dt`, '%H:%i') as hm, SUM(`counts`) AS total_count, 
       AVG(`counts`) AS avg_count, MAX(`counts`) AS max_count 
FROM pax_load_distribution , plans 
WHERE `pax_load_distribution`.`plan_id` = `plans`.`id` AND 
      `plans`.`dt` BETWEEN '2017-05-01' AND '2017-05-31' 
GROUP BY hm 
ORDER BY HOUR(hm) DESC, MINUTE(hm) ASC;
```

But as you can see, the query organize the 23 hours on top but not in a sequence from 23,00,01,02 etc. How can I make it such that the 23 hours are on top follow by 00,01 etc.

Comment: Does `dt` span multiple days?

Comment: Yes, it does span over a period of one month and collecting the hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `HOUR(dt + INTERVAL 1 HOUR)` instead of `HOUR(hm) DESC` in your `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: @ShawnAng, sorry. Try with `dt` please. I have upteted the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try : `ORDER BY (HUOUR(hm) * 60 + MINUTE(hm)) ASC`

Comment: Firstly, I think you have a typo in your HUOUR. Secondly - while this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.